# Spark job getting stuck forever

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, docker-compose, bitnami, spark-submit

I am trying to run it in the docker. But it is getting stuck after giving output. Am i missing something?

```
FROM bitnami/spark:3

USER root 
RUN curl https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-bundle/1.12.231/aws-java-sdk-bundle-1.12.231.jar --output /opt/bitnami/spark/jars/aws-java-sdk-bundle-1.12.231.jar RUN curl https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/java/dev/jets3t/jets3t/0.9.4/jets3t-0.9.4.jar --output /opt/bitnami/spark/jars/jets3t-0.9.4.jar RUN curl https://s3.amazonaws.com/redshift-downloads/drivers/jdbc/2.1.0.10/redshift-jdbc42-2.1.0.10.jar --output /opt/bitnami/spark/jars/redshift-jdbc42-2.1.0.10.jar RUN curl https://storage.googleapis.com/spark-lib/bigquery/spark-bigquery-with-dependencies_2.12-0.28.0.jar --output /opt/bitnami/spark/jars/spark-bigquery-with-dependencies_2.12-0.28.0.jar

COPY ./requirements_copy.txt / RUN pip install -r /requirements_copy.txt
```

```
version: '3'

services:
  spark:
    image: spark-air:latest
    environment:
      - SPARK_MODE=master
      - SPARK_RPC_AUTHENTICATION_ENABLED=no
      - SPARK_RPC_ENCRYPTION_ENABLED=no
      - SPARK_LOCAL_STORAGE_ENCRYPTION_ENABLED=no
      - SPARK_SSL_ENABLED=no
      - AWS_ACCESS_KEY=${AWS_ACCESS_KEY}
      - AWS_SECRET_KEY=${AWS_SECRET_KEY}

    volumes:
      - ./dags:/opt/bitnami/spark/dags/:rw
    ports:
      - '8090:8080'
  spark-worker:
    image: spark-air:latest
    environment:
      - SPARK_MODE=worker
      - SPARK_MASTER_URL=spark://spark:7077
      - SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY=1G
      - SPARK_WORKER_CORES=1
      - SPARK_RPC_AUTHENTICATION_ENABLED=no
      - SPARK_RPC_ENCRYPTION_ENABLED=no
      - SPARK_LOCAL_STORAGE_ENCRYPTION_ENABLED=no
      - SPARK_SSL_ENABLED=no
      - AWS_ACCESS_KEY=${AWS_ACCESS_KEY}
      - AWS_SECRET_KEY=${AWS_SECRET_KEY}
    volumes:
      - ./dags:/opt/bitnami/spark/dags/:rw
```

```py
from pyspark import SparkContext

sc = SparkContext("local", "First App")
    
data = [{"Category": 'A', "ID": 1, "Value": 121.44, "Truth": True},
        {"Category": 'B', "ID": 2, "Value": 300.01, "Truth": False},
        {"Category": 'C', "ID": 3, "Value": 10.99, "Truth": None},
        {"Category": 'E', "ID": 4, "Value": 33.87, "Truth": True}]
    
df = sc.parallelize(data)
df = df.collect()

print(df)
```

```
23/02/15 05:32:58 INFO Executor: Finished task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0). 1090 bytes result sent to driver
23/02/15 05:32:58 DEBUG ExecutorMetricsPoller: stageTCMP: (0, 0) -> 0
23/02/15 05:32:58 DEBUG TaskSchedulerImpl: parentName: , name: TaskSet_0.0, runningTasks: 0
23/02/15 05:32:58 DEBUG TaskSetManager: No tasks for locality level NO_PREF, so moving to locality level ANY
23/02/15 05:32:58 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0) in 1867 ms on d981929c6c2c (executor driver) (1/1)
23/02/15 05:32:58 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Removed TaskSet 0.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool 
23/02/15 05:32:58 INFO DAGScheduler: ResultStage 0 (collect at /opt/bitnami/spark/dags/test.py:12) finished in 3.275 s
23/02/15 05:32:58 DEBUG DAGScheduler: After removal of stage 0, remaining stages = 0
23/02/15 05:32:58 INFO DAGScheduler: Job 0 is finished. Cancelling potential speculative or zombie tasks for this job
23/02/15 05:32:58 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Killing all running tasks in stage 0: Stage finished
23/02/15 05:32:58 INFO DAGScheduler: Job 0 finished: collect at /opt/bitnami/spark/dags/test.py:12, took 3.794097 s
[{'Category': 'A', 'ID': 1, 'Value': 121.44, 'Truth': True}, {'Category': 'B', 'ID': 2, 'Value': 300.01, 'Truth': False}, {'Category': 'C', 'ID': 3, 'Value': 10.99, 'Truth': None}, {'Category': 'E', 'ID': 4, 'Value': 33.87, 'Truth': True}]
23/02/15 05:33:04 DEBUG ExecutorMetricsPoller: removing (0, 0) from stageTCMP
```

It is getting the expecting output but it is getting stuck after that for ever until i manually killing it. I want to integrate with airflow i can't manually kill it there.

Comment: `sc.stop()` at the end?

Comment: i added but now it is stuck on 23/02/15 06:08:32 INFO SparkContext: Successfully stopped SparkContext. i have to kill it manually.

Comment: how do you run your code?

Comment: i run the below command inside docker `spark-submit --master spark://spark-master:7077 ./dags/test.py`